# Extending the divs

Tags: css, html, extend

my page is structured like this:

When I load images in the 2nd div, only the inner div is extended, the parent is not. this is quite bothering, since the parent div has a border all arround. but the child2 div extends over it, outside the parent. both are set to relative and have min-height set to a value. Simplified version of the page:

```
    <div id="parent">
    <div id="child1">

    </div>
   <div id="child2">
       <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><!--here come the images-->
    </div>
</div>
```

here's the example: http://jsfiddle.net/TGCPn/1/

how can I make it that it will automaticaly extend?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the fixed width on the `#parent` and then adding `display: inline-block` on `#parent`

```
#parent
{
    display: inline-block;
    min-height:100px;
    border:solid 1px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TGCPn/2/)

Comment: that works. is there any way that the child1 would extend in the same way?

Comment: @user1126068 Adding `width: auto;` to the children should do it.

Comment: @user1126068 Ah right, then you can simply set `height:auto` on the children.

Comment: @user1126068 D'oh, I meant to say `height: 100%`, sorry my bad.

Comment: @user1126068 See here http://jsfiddle.net/TGCPn/3/ I also have removed `min-height` from the children too.

Answer (score 0):

Try `<div style="width:auto">` on the parent div